__dirname alternative for typescript(ESNext)
I want to retrieve an ejs file data and then sending the ejs file content as data in email as AWS SES. For this to get the path of the file I'm using __dirname. The code works on the localhost but when its hosted on aws it does not recognizes __dirname.

export const sendVerificationEmail = async (email: string, token: string, req: Request): Promise<void> => {
  // Read the template file for the verification email
  const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../views/verifyEmail.ejs');

  // Read the template file for the verification email
  const template = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf-8');

  // Render the email content with the verification link and other variables
  const emailContent = ejs.render(template, {
    verificationUrl: process.env.verificationLink,
    logo: process.env.LOGO,
    playStore: process.env.GOOGLE_PLAYSTORE,
    appleStore: process.env.APPLE_STORE,
  });

  // Prepare the email parameters
  const params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [email],
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Data: emailContent,
        },
      },
      Subject: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: 'Email Verification',
      },
    },
    Source: 'example@email.com', // Replace with your SES verified email
  };

  try {
    // Send the email using AWS SES
    await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
  } catch (error: any) {
    logger.error('AWS SES Error', {
      message: 'Error sending email',
      errorCode: 500,
      errorString: error.message,
      type: 'sendVerificationEmailError',
    });
    // Send a 500 status code with an error message.
    return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal server error: '+ error.message });
  }
};


ERROR:
 "message": "Internal server error: __dirname is not defined"

This question is similar to: Alternative for __dirname in Node.js when using ES6 modules. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Use process.cwd() or relative paths... There are a lot of solutions...

@Marc the link you provided shows a replacement for __dirname, the process.cwd() has no relation to the executed file and could be anything.
